# What is the purpose of DidSet in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I usually see tutorial where they use **DidSet** especially on Firebase apps, but I am not sure why we should use this instead of **ViewDidLoad** and when is it best to use them?

```
  var user: User? {
    didSet {
        observeUser()
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's like an observer to a value of a property , suppose you have a tableView with an array as the dataSource that can be changed anywhere in a long code , you can do this

```
 var tableArr:[String]=[]
 {
   didSet {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   } 
 }
```

instead of writing the reload line every change to the array

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer 

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't know the order in which things will happen. Assume that `user` can set *somehow*, and that we want to make sure our interface reflects that. By writing your code this way:

```
var user: User? {
    didSet {
        observeUser()
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    observeUser()
}
```

... you ensure that no matter *how and when and how many times* `user` is set, we will pick up its value and update the interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt 

Comment: Good discussion in WWDC 2018 video 233 showing an interesting use of `didSet`.